# How to validate a form?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have made a form using Google Apps Script's Ui Services and put it as a gadget inside a Sites page. The form has a SubmitButton. In the doPost I save the form data to a Google spreadsheet.

How can I validate form data before it gets saved?

- I couldn't use doPost because it clears the UI.
- I thought of using regular Button and handle validation and saving in a ServerClickHandler but I cannot get the all form data in e.parameter.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using the second approach I mentioned above using the click handler of a button instead of a submit button on a form. The problem was that for a strange reason the handler throws an exception if the callback element (panel or a grid) has a multi-select Listbox. If the listbox is removed, the handler works as it should. I posted it as an issue to Google forum.

I am still interested to see if this can be done in the doPost method using submit button and a form panel. I think it would be possible if we could prevent doPost from clearing out the UI somehow.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to prevent doPost from clearing the UI, but try putting the form in an HTML template. If it fails validation, you could reload the form and populate it with what they entered, marking the invalid entries. If it passes validation, you could display a confirmation page.